# How to change variables in the .env file dynamically in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a Laravel web app that allows an admin user to change some variables(such as database credentials) in the .env file using the web backend system. But how do I save the changes?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is no built in way to do that. If you really want to change the contents of the `.env` file, you'll have to use some kind of string replace in combination with PHP's file writing methods. For some inspiration, you should take a look at the `key:generate` command: [KeyGenerateCommand.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/KeyGenerateCommand.php#L38-L44):

```
$path = base_path('.env');

if (file_exists($path)) {
    file_put_contents($path, str_replace(
        'APP_KEY='.$this->laravel['config']['app.key'], 'APP_KEY='.$key, file_get_contents($path)
    ));
}
```

After the file path is built and the existence is checked, the command simply replaces `APP_KEY=[current app key]` with `APP_KEY=[new app key]`. You should be able to do the same string replacement with other variables.
Last but not least I just wanted to say that it might isn't the best idea to let users change the .env file. For most custom settings I would recommend storing them in the database, however this is obviously a problem if the setting itself is necessary to connect to the database.

Comment: Fails in my window environment. Any solution for that.

Comment: when i debug `$this->laravel['config'] gives error` it says error evaluating code

Answer (score 9):

Yet another implementation, in case you have something like:

A = B #this is a valid entry

In your .env file

```
public function updateEnv($data = array())
{
    if (!count($data)) {
        return;
    }

    $pattern = '/([^\=]*)\=[^\n]*/';

    $envFile = base_path() . '/.env';
    $lines = file($envFile);
    $newLines = [];
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        preg_match($pattern, $line, $matches);

        if (!count($matches)) {
            $newLines[] = $line;
            continue;
        }

        if (!key_exists(trim($matches[1]), $data)) {
            $newLines[] = $line;
            continue;
        }

        $line = trim($matches[1]) . "={$data[trim($matches[1])]}\n";
        $newLines[] = $line;
    }

    $newContent = implode('', $newLines);
    file_put_contents($envFile, $newContent);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Update Erick's answer with consideration of `$old` values covering sting, bool and null values.

```
public static function changeEnvironmentVariable($key,$value)
{
    $path = base_path('.env');

    if(is_bool(env($key)))
    {
        $old = env($key)? 'true' : 'false';
    }
    elseif(env($key)===null){
        $old = 'null';
    }
    else{
        $old = env($key);
    }

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        file_put_contents($path, str_replace(
            "$key=".$old, "$key=".$value, file_get_contents($path)
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To extend on lukasgeiter's and other's answer above, using regex to match the `.env` would be better, , as unlike `app.key`, the variable to put in `.env` may not be in the config.

Below is the code I used when experimenting on custom artisan command. This code generates a key for XChaCha encryption (`XCHACHA_KEY=?????`):

---

```
$path = base_path('.env');
if (file_exists($path)) {
    //Try to read the current content of .env
    $current = file_get_contents($path);   

    //Store the key
    $original = [];
    if (preg_match('/^XCHACHA_KEY=(.+)$/m', $current, $original)) { 
    //Write the original key to console
        $this->info("Original XChaCha key: $original[0]"); 

    //Overwrite with new key
        $current = preg_replace('/^XCHACHA_KEY=.+$/m', "XCHACHA_KEY=$b64", $current);

    } else {
    //Append the key to the end of file
        $current .= PHP_EOL."XCHACHA_KEY=$b64";
    }
    file_put_contents($path, $current);
}
$this->info('Successfully generated new key for XChaCha');
```

---

Using `preg_match()` allows the original key to be retrieved as needed, also allows the key to be changed even if the actual value is not known.

Answer (score 1):

**Another option is using a config file instead of changing the content in the `.env` file**.

Put all these in config files named like `newfile.php` inside the `config` folder, if you actually don't want to change `.env` content, and treat them as variable/array elements.

```
<?php

return [
    'PUSHER_APP_ID' => "",
    'PUSHER_APP_KEY' => "",
    'PUSHER_APP_SECRET' => "",
    'PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER' => "",
];
```

And get/set in controller like below:

```
config(['newfile.PUSHER_APP_ID' => 'app_id_value']); //set

config('newfile.PUSHER_APP_ID'); //get
```

Comment: and this config shouldn't be tracked by git therefore it should be in .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and have created the function below

```
public static function changeEnvironmentVariable($key,$value)
{
    $path = base_path('.env');

    if(is_bool(env($key)))
    {
        $old = env($key)? 'true' : 'false';
    }

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        file_put_contents($path, str_replace(
            "$key=".$old, "$key=".$value, file_get_contents($path)
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: $old might be undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
public function setEnvironmentValue($key, $value) {
 $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/.env';

 if (file_exists($path)) {
   if (getenv($key)) {
     //replace variable if key exit
     file_put_contents($path, str_replace(
       "$key=" . getenv($key), "$key=" . $value, file_get_contents($path)
     ));
   } else {
     //set if variable key not exit
     $file   = file($path);
     $file[] = "$key=" . $value;
     file_put_contents($path, $file);
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to update the .env key value in laravel is to add the below code in the controller function where you want to change .env values.

```
$key = 'VARIABLE_NAME';
$value = 'NEW VALUE';
file_put_contents(app()->environmentFilePath(), 
str_replace($key . '='. env($key),
$key . '=' . $value,file_get_contents(app()->environmentFilePath())));
```

The above lines of code will change the required key-value in the .env file. The next step is to clear the cache because the updated env value is not loaded; therefore, you need to reload configurations after successful change redirects to route with commands below.

```
Artisan::call('cache:clear');
Artisan::call('config:clear');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   /**
     * Update Laravel Env file Key's Value
     * @param string $key
     * @param string $value
     */
    public static function envUpdate($key, $value)
    {
        $path = base_path('.env');

        if (file_exists($path)) {

            file_put_contents($path, str_replace(
                $key . '=' . env($key), $key . '=' . $value, file_get_contents($path)
            ));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * @param string $key
 * @param string $val
 */
protected function writeNewEnvironmentFileWith(string $key, string $val)
{
    file_put_contents($this->laravel->environmentFilePath(), preg_replace(
        $this->keyReplacementPattern($key),
        $key . '=' . $val,
        file_get_contents($this->laravel->environmentFilePath())
    ));
}

/**
 * @param string $key
 * @return string
 */
protected function keyReplacementPattern(string $key): string
{
    $escaped = preg_quote('=' . env($key), '/');

    return "/^" . $key . "{$escaped}/m";
}
```

Comment: It's better to add explanation to the answer rather than code.