# How to change php dotenv (.env) variables dynamically in laravel or php?

Tags: php, laravel

I want something like this:

```
env('APP_ENV');
setenv('APP_ENV', 'testing');
env('APP_ENV');
```

Output :

```
staging
testing
```

I find one answer [How to change variables in the .env file dynamically in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307426/how-to-change-variables-in-the-env-file-dynamically-in-laravel)
but here .env is saved permanently, I don't want to save permanently.
How phpunit is doing this ? Because I can put in phpunit.xml this :

```
...
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
</php>
....
```

And env('APP_ENV') gives me 'testing'...

Comment: Why not just use config/app.php or config/mynewconfigfile.php?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change variables in the .env file dynamically in Laravel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307426/how-to-change-variables-in-the-env-file-dynamically-in-laravel)

Comment: because if 20 or more developers work on project high probability is that someone will use env() or $this->app->environment('local', 'dev') and app will not work as expected...

Comment: @veelen I explained why is not duplicated....

Comment: @fico7489 I'am sorry, you're right...

Comment: Here's how I figured out how to override env variables in Laravel Dusk https://stackoverflow.com/a/58473993/470749

Answer (score 7, accepted):

putenv() work like a charm :

```
echo env('APP_ENV');
putenv('APP_ENV=testing');
echo env('APP_ENV');
```

Output:

```
staging
testing
```

.env file is unattached ...

Comment: in laravel 7 this is not working. anyone can explain to me why the above is not code is not working.

Comment: yeah, I found a  way for that in laravel 7. this work for me $value = config('app.name');
reference https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#accessing-configuration-values

Comment: Since Laravel 5.8 this doesn't work! [Env variables became immutable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade#deferred-service-providers) so `putenv` doesn't change them.

Answer (score 4):

Laravel `.env` file values [are read by Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/configuration#environment-configuration) at the application bootstrap time and stored in the PHP [`$_ENV` global array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php) under the respective keys.

You can change any of those Laravel's (or other $_ENV's) values as simple as:

```php
// Assign the key's new value in the $_ENV global array
$_ENV['DB_CONNECTION'] = 'sqlite';
```

However if Laravel would take your change into account or not depends on the place in the code where you put this assignment.

**Development, Staging, Production Environments:**

Changing env values dynamically in memory for these environments is a bad idea.

Nevertheless to make this change you have to put your assignements in the Laravel bootstrap file before the framework instantiates [LoadEnvironmentVariables](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadEnvironmentVariables.html) class (for Lumen, the instantiation happens in `/bootstrap/app.php` file, for Laravel you could put your changes in the same file before application instantiation).

**Testing Environment**

However for testing environment changing env variables can be sometimes useful.

On top of [the PHPUnit capability](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.4/configuration.html#the-php-element) to change env variables at the test loading (as an example see the Laravel's `phpunit.xml` in your project folder):

```xml
<php>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
</php>
```

you can change the variables in the [PHPUnit's `setUp` function](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.4/fixtures.html#fixtures-examples-stacktest-php), (that in Laravel [also bootstraps the application](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/testing) - note the tests extend the Laravel `TestCase`) like the following:

```php
public $savedDBConnection;
public function setUp():void
{
    $this->savedDBConnection = $_ENV['DB_CONNECTION'];
    $_ENV['DB_CONNECTION'] = 'mysql';
    parent::setUp();
}
```

**Caveat**

Rather often you may face the unpleasant side effects of such dynamic changes (e.g. you test with in memory database and temporarily switch to on-disk test DB and some other test's [database refresh](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test) erases your on-disk test DB data).

To avoid this you have to save the variables before you change them in `setUp` method (as shown above) and restore them in [`tearDown` method](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.4/fixtures.html#), like this:

```php
public function tearDown():void
{
    $_ENV['DB_CONNECTION'] = $this->savedDBConnection;
    parent::tearDown();
}
```

**Alternative**

There is the other sometimes more applicable approach to change your `.env` variables for testing environment (credits go [here](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/environment-specific-variables-in-laravels-testing-environment/).): create the `.env.testing` file and load it when in tests. Briefly, add the following colde as explained in the comments

```php
// Add in tests/TestCase.php::createApplication() method
// below $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php' call.
if (file_exists(dirname(__DIR__) . '/.env.testing')) {
    (new \Dotenv\Dotenv(dirname(__DIR__), '.env.testing'))->load();
}
```

Now it is enough information to decide whether, when or how one needs / can  change the env variables dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Dotenv is immutable, so you cannot change value that is already assigned. (https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv#immutability)

PHPUnit is setting this values during bootstrap, before laravel is started. Laravel dotenv is running in immutable mode, so values already set, are not overridden.

Comment: Hmmm, but I want change .env during laravel bootstrap...Why phpunit can set during bootstrap and laravel can't during bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

Notice:

### Laravel ~5.7:

`env('AAA') = getenv('AAA')`
→ To set the value of the variable AAA, simply use `putenv('AAA', 'true');`

→ env('AAA') will become TRUE

You can check the details of getenv() here
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php

### Laravel 5.8~:

From Laravel 5.8 onward, env() no longer uses getenv() anymore.

Therefore, `env('AAA') != getenv('AAA')`

→　So even though we use `putenv('AAA', 'true');` the value of env('AAA') will not change.

Because the behavior of the env() becomes

```
env('AAA') = Env::getRepository()->get('AAA');
```

→ To set the value of the variable AAA, use `Env::getRepository()->set('AAA','true')`
→ env('AAA') will become TRUE

You can check the details of getenv() of Laravel 5.8 here
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php

Answer (score 0):

Considering laravel keeps messing around env() helper every now and then, its easier to simply use `getenv()` instead of `env()`. Then it should be ok to set the env var any time using `putenv()`.