# What is the best practice to deal with application .env files in development and production in Docker?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have .env file which is used by dockerized PHP application. Aplication loads variables from `.env` file using `dotenv` and initialize DB connection. The .env file has basic DB config in it:

```
DB_ENGINE = "mysql"
DB_HOST = "host"
DB_NAME = "db"
DB_USERNAME = "user"
DB_PASSWORD = "pass"
```

Obviously, those credentials will be different in the dev environment and in the production environment. My question is, how do deal with those different `.env` files when building app images for development and production? `.env` *MUST* be physically at the root app folder because it's been loaded via `Dotenv`.

For now I have created `.env.dev` and `.env.prod` files. I may use 2 different Dockerfiles for dev and prod and just run `COPY` command. But I don't think this is a good practice. I'm using GitLab CI for deploying - I build app image and run container in production. I was also thinking about storing `.env.prod` file in the Gitlab file variable.  What is the best practice in my case?

*EDIT*
I temporary solved my problem with multi stage build and targets But I don't think is a good practice:

```
FROM php:7.4-cli as base
...

FROM base as dev
COPY ./.env.dev /usr/src/myapp/.env

FROM base as prod
COPY ./.env.prod /usr/src/myapp/.env
```

Comment: Define them as ENV variable at container's run time. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41827665/how-to-change-php-dotenv-env-variables-dynamically-in-laravel-or-php

Comment: And another related link is https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file

Comment: This doesn't physically create `.env` file. Therefore I get the following error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException: Unable to read any of the environment file(s) at /usr/src/myapp/.env`