# Update .env value via Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, environment-variables, laravel-5.1

Example, if my **.env** is

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_URL=http://localhost:8888/
APP_DEBUG=true
FACEBOOK_APP_ID = ABC
```

I know in Laravel we can do access our .env file by doing this

```
echo env('APP_ENV'); --> 'local'
echo env('APP_URL'); --> 'http://localhost:8888/'
```

but I wonder if there is a way to programmatically set it

```
Ex. env('APP_ENV') == 'production';
```

Comment: You'd have to write to the file, but it's typically best for security to have your Laravel install configured not to have permissions to do so. `config('app.env', 'production')` would override the config value for the *current* request, though.

Comment: I just using APP_ENV as an example, but I actually want to update something else like FACEBOOK_APP_ID, base on a certain account, etc ...

Comment: If I want to update my `FACEBOOK_APP_ID` in my .env file will this `config('FACEBOOK_APP_ID.env', '123')` works ? Or something similar to that ?

Comment: No, that won't. You really should be changing the `.env` file either via a deployment system or by editing it directly.

Comment: .env file isn't supposed to be your config file, but rather your template for your config. Your settings should be stored outside, ideally in your hosting as environment variables. Also it's a very bad practice security-wise to be able to edit it like this... You really don't want to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$path = base_path('.env');

if (file_exists($path)) {
file_put_contents($path, str_replace(
    'APP_KEY='.$this->laravel['config']['app.key'], 'APP_KEY='.$key, file_get_contents($path)
));
}
```

taken from here [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307426/how-to-change-variables-in-the-env-file-dynamically-in-laravel)

Comment: What if the I want to update a custom key like FACEBOOK_APP_ID to anything string. Will your suggestion still work ?

Comment: this should work for any var you want to update just swap out "APP_KEY" for "FACEBOOK_APP_ID"

Comment: Ok. What is this `$this->laravel['config']['app.key']` do ? I don't think I should that when I want to use this `FACEBOOK_APP_ID`...

Comment: that takes the current text for "APP_KEY" and  the next line replaces that key with the new one

Comment: Can you check my first param of str_replace() ? `'FACEBOOK_APP_ID='.$this->laravel['config']['app.key']` ...

Comment: Just curious, if I should it blank or leave it as what you suggested.

Comment: please try and do a little yourself to see what you come up with, this will help you learn the best.

Comment: This `$this->laravel['config']['app.key']` doesn't work on my senario. because my FACEBOOK_APP_ID is not == to app.key ..

Answer (score 11):

This might help.

```
function setEnv($name, $value)
{
    $path = base_path('.env');
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        file_put_contents($path, str_replace(
            $name . '=' . env($name), $name . '=' . $value, file_get_contents($path)
        ));
    }
}
setEnv('APP_ENV','abc');
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. Thanks for improving the answer's reference value and making it more understandable!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
putenv("APP_ENV=production");
```

because `env` is just a convenience wrapper around `getenv` which does some type conversion.

Note: this is not permanent as it will be overwritten by `.env` when the next request happens.

Comment: @Linesofcode that's true, this will not work in Laravel 5.8+ because the method `env` was changed and no longer uses `getenv`

Answer (score 1):

You can easily update or insert the variable in `.env` file by using `syamsoul/laravel-set-env` package.

.

1. Install via composer

```
composer require syamsoul/laravel-set-env
```

.

2. Just run this code

```
use SoulDoit\SetEnv\Env;

$envService = new Env(); 
$envService->set("MY_APP_NAME", "My Laravel Application");
```

.

3. Or, run artisan command

```
php artisan souldoit:set-env
```

- You will be prompted about the variable name and the value.

.

4. Or, same artisan command, but just straightaway put the variable name and value into the argument.

```
php artisan souldoit:set-env "APP_NAME=My New Laravel Name"
```

.
.

P/S: Tested on Laravel 10 and above and it is working fine.

For more info: https://github.com/syamsoul/laravel-set-env