# Changing env values via controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables

Is there any ways that I could change my `.env` file values from controllers in laravel?

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727510/update-env-value-via-laravel/42727702#42727702) but it returns

> Undefined property:
>   App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PerformanceController::$laravel

## code

```
$path = base_path('.env');
$key = false;

if (file_exists($path)) {
  file_put_contents($path, str_replace(
    'APP_KEY='.$this->laravel['config']['app.key'], 'APP_DEBUG='.$key, file_get_contents($path)
   ));
}
```

I want to have options in my admin panel to change debug mode between true or false, same as we have artisan commands in controller like `Artisan::call('down')` or `Artisan::call('up')` something like that.

## Update

Now I have this code

```
$path = base_path('.env');
$key = 'true';

if (file_exists($path)) {
  file_put_contents($path, str_replace(
    'APP_DEBUG='.config('app.debug'), 'APP_DEBUG='.$key, file_get_contents($path)
  ));
}
```

this code does work but the issue is that it doesn't remove old value.

#### Before

```
APP_DEBUG=false
```

#### After

```
APP_DEBUG=truefalse
or
APP_DEBUG=falsefalse
```

any idea?

Comment: I think this link might be helpful: https://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/change-the-env-dynamically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40450162/3854365 check this answer

Comment: @HirenGohel I didn't understand that. where data comes from? where we set values? how to update? it's so incomplete.

Comment: @mafortis: See there, `something()` function contains `$env_update` array which you want to update data into env file. And calling other function named as `changeEnv` to update the datas.

Comment: @mafortis:The author has also created a package for the same, you can review it here: https://github.com/Brotzka/laravel-dotenv-editor

Comment: From the link that you provided, use the [next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50965881/3226121)

Comment: @HirenGohel that package has 2 issues i used to use that, `1` security `2` generated file can't accept white space.

Answer (score 1):

it is not good idea to change your .env configuration. instead of that, use this code where you want change your APP_KEY.

be sure you did not cache your config

```
config(['app.key' => 'YOUR_NEW_KEY']);
```

Comment: in that case i should leave my env values empty?

Comment: no, it will replace default configuration of config/app.php whenever you use this part of code. when you do not use this code, app.php use .env values to populate its values.

Comment: that's why i need to replace env file values because laravel uses them as priority, and this code didn't change anything in my config/app.php as well.

Comment: I got what you want, you could do something which i did not tested that before. create new Middleware for your application and place it on the top of $middleware property of app/http/kernel.php class. on the handle(), set your new configuration. please tell me it was helpful or not after test.it is very close to entry point of your application

Answer (score 0):

instead of using 
`$this->laravel['config']['app.key']`
try `config('app.key')`

Comment: ok this doesn't return the error but there is strange issue, when i use `config('app.key')` it changes the `APP_KEY` to `APP_DEBUG` in env file but when I use `config('app.debug')` it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Because you told your code to find the `APP_KEY` and to replace with `APP_DEBUG`.  Change `APP_KEY` to `APP_DEBUG`

Comment: now i have this `'APP_DEBUG='.config('app.debug'), 'APP_DEBUG='.$key, file_get_contents($path)` but doesn't make change in env file

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why do you think that this solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

use this DotenvEditor::setKey('APP_KEY', 'new_value')->save();