# How to fill dropbox secretkey to .env by getting data from database (Model) on Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hi I use Spatie's backup package to backup database to Dropbox. I put dropbox secret info directly to .env as below code.

```
DROPBOX_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxx
DROPBOX_TOKEN=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

That's not comfortable once need to change these key. So, Is it possible to get key form database(Model) and put to .env via some method in controller?.

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: maybe in provider, so it reads it every request. or fetch it from the database before calling the corresponding method that uses drop box and put it in environment variable. either way works fine. to put it in environment variables just `putenv("DROPBOX_SECRET=".$dropbox_secret); putenv("DROPBOX_TOKEN=".$dropbox_token);`

Comment: I directly put ==> putenv("DROPBOX_SECRET=".$mykey); <== to controller but value not changed.

Comment: May this help you => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307426/how-to-change-variables-in-the-env-file-dynamically-in-laravel

Comment: Which controller?? Please provide more details about your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change variables in the .env file dynamically in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307426/how-to-change-variables-in-the-env-file-dynamically-in-laravel)